# Jenkins messes up system time while running Unit tests with usage of RevisionRepository

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

We are working on revisioning framework for our application by using spring Envers support. 
We prepared a set of integration tests, which are first inserting data into database and then querying it with some conditions, to check that versioning is working fine. Rows are inserted with milliseconds delays, to ensure, that two rows will not have the same RevisionTimestamp. All tests work fine, when are executed on local environments, but when are moved to Jenkins, they are failing randomly. 
After investigation we figured it out, that even though inserts are executed sequentially by on thread, sometimes RevisionTimestamp is set backwards. 
This is due to the fact, that system clock on Jenkins sometimes is moved backwards by unknown force.

Here is an example of log:

```
2018-12-19 11:02:33.615 [main] INFO  d.e.s.l.u.b.core.TemporalHandler - Just before going into entityJpaRepository.findLastChangeRevision - 2018-12-19T11:02:33.615639 6847516000080345
2018-12-19 11:02:33.377 [main] INFO  d.e.s.l.u.b.core.TemporalHandler - Just after going into entityJpaRepository.findLastChangeRevision - 2018-12-19T11:02:33.377086 6847516058513093
```

Notice that first timestamp from first log line is higher than first timestamp from second line, but second timestamp from first line is lower than second timestamp from second line.

Log comes from following piece of code:

```
@Component("temporalHandler")
public class TemporalHandler<T extends Temporal<T, N>, N> implements EntityRevisionsTemporalApi<T, N> {
        private final static transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TemporalHandler.class);
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7854492585050762415L;

        @PersistenceContext
        @Autowired
        public transient EntityManager em;

        protected transient GenericEntityRepository<?, N> entityJpaRepository;

        /**
         * Setting the entity repository instance dynamically by the consumer component
         *
         * @param entityJpaRepository instance of the entity repository that needs to be
         *                            audited
         */
        public void setEntityJpaRepository(GenericEntityRepository<?, N> entityJpaRepository) {
            this.entityJpaRepository = entityJpaRepository;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "hiding"})
        @Override
        public T getEntityLatestRevision(@NotNull N id) {
            try {
                log.info("Just before going into entityJpaRepository.findLastChangeRevision - " + LocalDateTime.now() + " " + System.nanoTime());
                var result = entityJpaRepository.findLastChangeRevision(id);
                log.info("Just after going into entityJpaRepository.findLastChangeRevision - " + LocalDateTime.now() + " " + System.nanoTime());
                return result
                        .map(r -> ((Revision<Integer, T>) r).getEntity())
                        .orElse(null);
            } finally {
                log.info("Just after going into result.map.orElse - " + LocalDateTime.now() + " " + System.nanoTime());
            }

        }
    }
```

And Generic repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericEntityRepository<T, N> extends RevisionRepository<T, N, Integer>, JpaRepository<T, N> {
}
```

We are trying to solve this issue for several days already, but with no success. We are 99% sure it's related to something on Jenkins, but we have no idea what could be different there. 
On local environments both dates from the log are in sync, so as expected, both timestamps from first line are before both timestamps from second.

Maybe someone of you will have a clue, what should we check on Jenkins?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thx.

@Update
    We have some more logs, we know, when time is changed, but still no idea, why this could happen. Checkout last 3 lines of this log:

```
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#152]
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#152]
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.h.e.j.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.h.e.i.StatefulPersistenceContext - Initializing non-lazy collections
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.h.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache - Located HQL query plan in cache (select e__ from entity.TestEntity_AUD e__ where e__.originalId.REV.id = (select max(e2__.originalId.REV.id) from entity.TestEntity_AUD e2__ where e2__.originalId.REV.id <= :revision and e__.originalId.id = e2__.originalId.id) and e__.REVTYPE <> :_p0 and e__.originalId.id = :_p1)
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.h.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache - Located HQL query plan in cache (select e__ from entity.TestEntity_AUD e__ where e__.originalId.REV.id = (select max(e2__.originalId.REV.id) from entity.TestEntity_AUD e2__ where e2__.originalId.REV.id <= :revision and e__.originalId.id = e2__.originalId.id) and e__.REVTYPE <> :_p0 and e__.originalId.id = :_p1)
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.h.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan - Find: select e__ from dk.eg.sd.loen.utility.bitemporal.entity.TestEntity_AUD e__ where e__.originalId.REV.id = (select max(e2__.originalId.REV.id) from entity.TestEntity_AUD e2__ where e2__.originalId.REV.id <= :revision and e__.originalId.id = e2__.originalId.id) and e__.REVTYPE <> :_p0 and e__.originalId.id = :_p1
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.h.engine.spi.QueryParameters - Named parameters: {_p1=1, _p0=DEL, revision=152}
2018-12-19 18:32:54.853 [main] TRACE o.h.e.j.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Registering last query statement [HikariProxyPreparedStatement@773469572 wrapping prep1068: select testentity0_.id as id1_1_, testentity0_.rev as rev2_1_, testentity0_.revtype as revtype3_1_, testentity0_.revision_system_time as revision4_1_, testentity0_.revision_system_time_mod as revision5_1_, testentity0_.revision_time as revision6_1_, testentity0_.revision_time_mod as revision7_1_, testentity0_.effective_end_time as effectiv8_1_, testentity0_.effective_end_time_mod as effectiv9_1_, testentity0_.effective_start_time as effecti10_1_, testentity0_.effective_start_time_mod as effecti11_1_, testentity0_.employee_id as employe12_1_, testentity0_.employee_id_mod as employe13_1_, testentity0_.first_name as first_n14_1_, testentity0_.first_name_mod as first_n15_1_, testentity0_.last_name as last_na16_1_, testentity0_.last_name_mod as last_na17_1_, testentity0_.salary as salary18_1_, testentity0_.salary_mod as salary_19_1_ from test_entity_aud testentity0_ where testentity0_.rev=(select max(testentity1_.rev) from test_entity_aud testentity1_ where testentity1_.rev<=? and testentity0_.id=testentity1_.id) and testentity0_.revtype<>? and testentity0_.id=?]
2018-12-19 18:32:54.631 [main] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [entity.TestEntity_AUD#component[id,REV]{REV=org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#152, id=1}]
2018-12-19 18:32:54.632 [main] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [entity.TestEntity_AUD#component[id,REV]{REV=org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#152, id=1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is revisionTimestamp, is it of date format and what is it being used for ?

From the information shared, here's what I think:

If you are using timestamp as a unique constraint or for ordering it is not the best practice.

Time can go backwards sometimes on operating systems.
[NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) process is used to sync time on your computer. If this process is out of sync on one of your servers, it can report an earlier time than actual time. If you have multiple servers running, time can vary. All the servers may not have clock in sync with each other upto millisecond precision. Ordering wont be guaranteed across servers.

There are two kinds of clocks:
Monotonic Clocks: report time duration elapsed 
Wall clocks: report what time is it

**Possible Solutions:**
Probably look into auto incrementing ids or something like snowflakes for versioning.

Increase the time offset I guess in the integration tests between consecutive inserts.

See if you can rely on databases createdAt timestamp column
Check what precision level LocalDateTime.now() offers

Comment: RevisionTimestamp is used to keep information about create or update time. It's set by UpdateTimestamp annotation and is not used as an ID. The type is java.sql.Timestamp.
I've already tried increasing time gap between each update, but it didn't solve the issue. I have to check if there is any synchronizations issues. For sure all tests are running against the same jvm and in one thread, so I'm pretty sure it is not related to multi-threading.
Looks like Jenkins (or something on Jenkins server) is playing with system clock, which is used by hibernate to set UpdateTimestamp annotated fields

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak directly related to `hibernate-envers`.  I do not have much experience with precisely how or the ways in which `spring-data-envers` wraps our library, so I can't go into depth about what their contracts provide or how they work.

With that said, I am much inclined to be in agreement with Ankit here and its exactly why the design of the revision-entity table, `REVINFO` is the way it is.

```
REVINFO
------------------------------------
REV      numeric   auto_increment PK
REVTSTMP timestamp
```

All audit rows that `hibernate-envers` generates has a foreign-key back to this table structure, the `REV` column in each of the entity audit tables point to a row in this table.  This means that for all changes within the scope of a **single** transaction, there will only ever be **ONE** `REV` and `REVTSTMP` value.

When `hibernate-envers` wants to return audit changes for entities using any form of order, we do not use the `REVTSTMP` column at all, we use the `REV` column.  We use the `REV` column because its guaranteed to be order deterministic because its based on some database generated construct; whether that is an identity, auto_increment, or sequence backed object.

For what its worth, the `REVTSTMP` column is simply informational.  Its meant to provide the user or app with some context about when the audit change took place, but we never use that column when asked to provide ordered dependency of changes; we instead rely solely on `REV`.

I would suggest modifying your tests to rely on `REV` here instead.